# Video "no signal" but computer still running

Tags: video, graphics-card, signal

**Update**
Not doing anything in particular during these blackouts...  Usually just when im doing nothing, sometimes im watching a video, sometimes playing a game...  but mostly just whenever.  I mostly watch movies so i dont do any intense gaming.

Also when i remote connected to the computer after it blacked out, pretty much everything was crashing like Explorer, couldnt open up ctrl panel or anything.  I was able to open CCC and click Identify monitor.  1 of my computer monitor came on, the other one (thru HDMI) the receiver no longer said "No Signal" but the tv was not displaying any images and CCC said it was unable to extend to that monitor for some reason.

***Original Post***
Im assuming this is a video card issue, not sure if I should RMA the card.  Thought someone might know a good way to test this problem.

**Problem:**

- My receiver says "no signal" and both the tv/monitor go to sleep.
- This occurs randomly sometimes its fine no problem for days, then it will do it a few 
  times in a day.
- It seems to fix itself after rebooting the computer, which I find that to be odd.
- I receive no errors or crashing of the computer.
- I know the computer is still running because I can remote connect to it, and from my 
  laptop I can visually see everything.  Also I can access the drives via network.
- During bootup of the computer the fan on the videocard ran so loud it sounded 
  like a desk fan.  This has only happened once though.
  Video card is connected output HDMI to receiver, which is connected to TV and 
  second monitor, output via DVI to a regular monitor

**Things I've tried:**

- I have reinstalled Windows.
- I have updated the CCC drivers.

**My rig:**

- Win 7 Pro 64-bit
- Mobo: GIGABYTE GA-X58A-UD3R LGA 1366 Intel X58 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel
- Video: XFX HD-695A-CNFC Radeon HD 6950 2GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.1 x16 HDCP Ready 
     CrossFireX Support Video Card with Eyefinity
- PSU: CORSAIR Professional Series HX750 (CMPSU-750HX) 750W ATX12V 2.3 / EPS12V 2.91 SLI 
     Ready CrossFire Ready 80 PLUS SILVER Certified Modular Active PFC Power Supply
- CPU: Intel Core i7-950 Bloomfield 3.06GHz LGA 1366 130W Quad-Core Processor BX80601950
- RAM: G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 12GB (3 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1333 (PC3 10666) Desktop 
     Memory Model F3-10666CL9T-12GBRL
- UPS: CyberPower CP1350AVRLCD 1350 VA 810 Watts UPS
- CD:  LITE-ON Black 12X Blu-ray Burner with Blu-ray 3D feature SATA IHBS112-29 - OEM

Comment: random in the middle of you doing something on that computer?  The fan kicking up way higher than "normal high", during boot might indicate that the temps on it were "allowed" to get too high. Like some software that is attempting control of the Thermal response of the fan failed to maintain temps proper. Need to know the GPU temps before failure. a Cool little Gadget that is telling me temperature of my ATI is "Gpu Observer" Ati should be doing a "VPU recover" I assume these blackouts are not when "gaming"? and if anything is going bad with temps it is a slow burn?

Comment: The update sounds more like some sort of "memory leak", not nessisarily an actual memory leak, but some misbehaving program or driver that is messing up. Via the updateed info you provided, I would want to monitor even more things in the system. The I/O and memory use of tasks and all (task manager or resource monitor). Also Testing by turning off (or ending) certian programs or devices, one at a time, an attempt to find the offender. Usually this starts with weird or different things that would be first suspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try disconnecting it from the Receiver, i had a similar problem and this solved it.